# return element from a list that are not included to another list

Tags: list, scheme, racket

Hi I want to write a simple function that take 2 lists and  returns the elements from the first list that are not included to the other list.

For example l1 '( 1 2 3 4)  l2 '( 5 6 2 8 3)

the return should be '( 1 4)

Currently, I have this code:

```
(define (iteration2)
    (define listA '())
    (for ([list1 a])
        (for ([list2 b])
          (if (equal? list1 list2)
              '()
              (cons list1 listA))))
    listA)
```

thanks

Comment: Firstly I tried to do it recursively but without success.. And then I tried to do it with 2 "for loops" and a local list smth like that..

Comment: (define (iteration2)
 
  
    (define listA '())
    
    (for ([list1 a])
      
      ( for( [list2 b])
    
     ( if (equal? list1 list2)
        ;  
         '()
         ( cons list1 listA)
    )))
  
  listA
    
  )

Comment: People will be more likely to help you if you post code. Even if the code doesn't work. That way we can help you improve your code rather than writing solutions from scratch. EDIT: you beat me to it.

Comment: It's better not to post the code for the recursion because it's totally crap. My problem is that I have to parse both lists for each element so it was a little bit confusing. with double for loop seems more easy but i do not get the result I want..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before writing a loop (or recursing), it's always advisable to see if one of the build-in functions can do the looping for you. In your case, you want to filter a list, so:

```
(define (first-not-second l1 l2)
  (filter 
   (lambda (x) (not (member x l2))) 
   l1))
```

such as

```
(first-not-second '(1 2 3 4) '(5 6 2 8 3))
=> '(1 4)
```

The Racket `for`version would be

```
(define (first-not-second l1 l2)
  (for/list ((x l1) #:unless (member x l2))
    x))
```

and the classical "helper function style" gives

```
(define (first-not-second l1 l2)

  (define (first-not-second-helper l1 l2)
    (if (empty? l1)
        '()
        (let ((x (car l1)))
          (if (member x l2)
              (first-not-second-helper (cdr l1) l2)
              (cons x (first-not-second-helper (cdr l1) l2))))))

  (first-not-second-helper l1 l2))
```

In any case, you don't need to loop over the second list because you can use the build-in `member` procedure.

Comment: Wow.. Exactly what I was looking for.... Thanks a lot buddy!

I am new in Scheme I do not know most of the build-in functions!

I tried the first one and its running like a charm.

thanks again...

Answer (score 1):

The procedure performs a list *difference* operation, it's useful to think of this as a set difference. The trick is to use the [`member`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/private/list..rkt%29._member%29%29) to determine if an element is in a list. I'll not spoil the fun for you by giving a straight answer, just fill-in the blanks in this skeleton of a solution:

```
(define (diff l1 l2)
  (cond (<???>  ; if the 1st list is empty
         <???>) ; then we're done building the answer, return the empty list
        (<???>  ; if the 1st list's current element is not a member of 2nd list
         (cons <???>             ; then cons the 1st list's current element
               (diff <???> l2))) ; and advance the recursion
        (else                    ; otherwise
         (diff <???> l2))))      ; just advance the recursion
```

Notice that we only traverse the first list, the second list remains constant through the iteration.